# Unity - adjusting RigidBody position with MovePosition()

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I made myself a little character controller that uses primarily non kinematic RigidBody with AddForce() method (VelocityChange ForceMode). Then I tried to make crouching (simple resize of capsule collider) and it was sort of jittery, so every frame I adjust the Y position of RigidBody by the amount the player un/crouched. The crouch jitter is gone, but now the RigidBody moves very slow during the un/crouching. So it is a big no-no to combine these two, or should it be possible? This is the MovePosition part. The controller is split into mulitple scripts and has over 1000 lines, so cannot post it all here. Just want an answer if combining these two movement methods is OK. Thanks for reading!

```
// Gradually adjust current height to target height
            if (!Mathf.Approximately(heightTarget, currentHeight))
            {
                float oldHeight = currentHeight;
                currentHeight = Mathf.Lerp(currentHeight, heightTarget, crouchSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                float camHeightDifference = (standingHeight - currentHeight) / 2;

                player.Height = currentHeight;
                player.targetCamYPos = initialCameraPos - camHeightDifference;
                player.Rigidbody.MovePosition(player.transform.position += Vector3.up * (currentHeight - oldHeight) / 2);
            }
```

I tried to experiment a bit with the Rigidbody properties and it still behaves the same - during the un/crouching the velocity of RigidBody is changed even though I am just adding/subtracting the Y position.

Answer (score 0):

I just got an heureka moment :D It is possible to combine these two, works pretty well actually. I was just updating the Rigidbody position in Update loop instead of FixedUpdate loop, where all my other physics is being calculated. What a stupid mistake, but maybe someone looking at this will have the same problem. Cheers!

Edit: The order I combined them in is MovePosition() first and then AddForce(). I don't know if swapping them would do anything different, so I thought I'd mention this detail.